# Does this question provide enough information?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we are asked to prove that the quotient space $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb R$  equipped with the quotient topology is compact. Has this question provided enough information for us to answer it? Do we not need to know the topology given to $\mathbb R$? I ask this because we can attach a wide variety of topologies to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You may assume that $\Bbb R$ has the usual (Euclidean) topology unless some other topology is specified.

Comment: Yes, it is. If $\Bbb R$ were given the discrete topology, for instance, the quotient would be discrete and infinite and therefore not compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you.

Comment: @Brian: Perhaps you should write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @mixedmath: Done. (I too like to get questions off the Unanswered list.)

Comment: I'd like a little clarification, as there are two possible meanings  of $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$. One is that this term means the quotient group of the additive group $\mathbb R$ by the additive subgroup $\mathbb Z$; this group is often called the circle group, and is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of complex numbers of modules 1, and is compact.  The other  is that the symbol $X/A$ means $X$ with $A$ shrunk to a point; in this case the result looks non compact!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may generally assume that any $\Bbb R^n$ has the usual (Euclidean) topology unless some other topology is explicitly specified or made very clear by the context.